# How do I get a remaining time to finish activity?

Tags: java, android, datetime, time, alarmmanager

How i can get remaining time from current time to a time i've installed? In my app I've been already using `AlarmManager` library and I've tried
to write something like this:

```
    long remaining_hours = System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000 - _hour;
    long remaining_minutes = System.currentTimeMillis()/1000 - _minute;
```

but it is not working. Could you give me an example how to deal with it?

Comment: What do you mean with "time I've installed"?

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you've written allready that code:

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormatUCT = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm"); 
dateFormatUCT.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UCT"));

String deadline = dateFormatUCT.format(new Date());
```

Now  you will use the `parse` method of the *same* date format you created to change `String` back into a date:

```
Date deadlineDate = dateFormatUCT.parse(deadline);
```

To compare if another date (let's say: `actualDate`) has passed `deadline`, it sufficient to do:

```
if(actualDate.after(deadlineDate)) {
    // deadline has passed, do something
}
```

Then if you would like to get the time difference in milliseconds between them, ypu would write code like this:

```
long timeDiff = currentDate.getTime() - deadlineDate.getTime();
```

NOTICE: To convert this millisecond value to other units (like days, minutes, seconds etc) use methods of the [`TimeUnit`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/TimeUnit.html) class :

```
TimeUnit.SECONDS.toSeconds(timeDiff);
```

If you still have a question, please feel free to ask